# Find number of elements smaller than a given element in BST

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I have been struggling with this problem for a while and I am a Python beginner when it comes to BST, so I would appreciate some help. I am dynamically adding elements from an (unsorted) array into BST. That part is fine, I know how to do that. The next step, proved to be impossible with my current skill set. As I am adding elements to the tree, I need to be able to find current rank of any element in the tree. I know there are subtleties in this problem, so I would need help to at least find the number of nodes that are below the given node in BST. For example, in this case, node 15 has nodes 10,5 and 13 below it, so the function will return 3. Here is my existing code [this is a problem from Cracking the coding interview, chapter 11]

```
class Node:

"""docstring for Node"""
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
    self.numLeftChildren=0
    self.numRightChildren=0
class BSTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def addNode(self, data):
        return Node(data)

    def insert(self, root, data):
        if root == None:
            return self.addNode(data)
        else:
            if data <= root.data:
                root.numLeftChildren+=1
                root.left = self.insert(root.left, data)
            else:
                root.numRightChildren+=1
                root.right = self.insert(root.right, data)
            return root 
    def getRankOfNumber(self,root,x):
        if root==None:
            return 0
        else:
            if x>root.data :
                return self.getRankOfNumber(root.right,x)+root.numLeftChildren+1
            elif root.data==x:
                return root.numLeftChildren
            else:
                return self.getRankOfNumber(root.left,x)   
BTree=BSTree()
root=BTree.addNode(20)
BTree.insert(root,25)
BTree.insert(root,15)
BTree.insert(root,10)
BTree.insert(root,5)
BTree.insert(root,13)
BTree.insert(root,23)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go by this approach:

```
1. Have 2 more fields in each node numLeftChildren and numRightChildren.
2. Initialize both of them to 0 when you create a new node.
3. At the time of insertion, you make a comparison if the newly added node's
key is less than root's key than you increment, root's numLeftChildren and
call recursion on root's left child with the new node.
4. Do Same thing if new node's key is greater than root's key.
```

Now, come back to your original problem, You have to find out the number of children in left subtree. Just find out that node in O(logN) time and just print the **numLeftChildren**

**Time Complexity: O(logN)**

PS: I have added another field numRightChildren which you can remove if you are always interested in knowing the number of nodes in left subtree only.

Comment: I think this is the closest to what I am looking. I modified the code a bit. When I run it, I see that left and right count are correct for each node. How do I return the values? When I try to return the value I get the message  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'numLeftChildren'

Comment: Just return the node on which numLeftChildren you want and after coming out of recursion..You get the node which you have searched and then print its value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I don't have enough knowledge to implement this. I will return to this problem in a couple of weeks and see if I can solve it.

Comment: Actually, after some modifications to find function, I managed to return the correct number of left nodes.

Comment: I have updated the code with the final solution. The problem was to find all elements in the tree that are smaller than the given element. So, for 24 it would be 6.

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your BST to contain the number of nodes beneath each node.

Or you could iterate over a traditional BST from least to greatest, counting as you go, and stop counting when you find a node of the required value.

Comment: Let me correct myself: I would need to know the number of left and right nodes. So, for 15, it would return 3, but for 10, it would return 1,1 (1 on the left and one on the right)

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the code by using just instances of the `Node` class, as your `BSTree` instance operates on the root node anyway. Another optimization could be to not represent duplicate values as separate nodes, but instead use a counter of occurrences of the key:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.num_left_children = 0
        self.occurrences = 1

    def insert(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
            self.num_left_children += 1
        elif data > self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
        else:
            self.occurrences += 1

    def get_rank(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            return self.left.get_rank(data)
        elif data > self.data:
            return (self.occurrences + self.num_left_children +
                    self.right.get_rank(data))
        else:
            return self.num_left_children
```

Demo:

```
root = Node(20)
root.insert(25)
root.insert(15)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(10)
root.insert(5)
root.insert(13)
root.insert(23)

print(root.get_rank(15))  # 4
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below function to find the number of the nodes in the tree (including the root).

```
def countNodes(self, root):
    if root == None:
        return 0
    else
        return (1 + countNodes(root.left) + countNodes(root.right));
```

To find the number of nodes that lie below `root`, subtract `1` from the value returned by the function. I think this will help get you started on the problem.

Your code will look like:

class Node:
"""docstring for Node"""
def **init**(self, data):
    self.data = data
    self.left=None
    self.right=None
    self.depth=0

class BSTree:
    def **init**(self):
        self.root = None

```
def addNode(self, data):
    return Node(data)

def insert(self, root, data):
    if root == None:
        return self.addNode(data)
    else:
        if data <= root.data:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, data)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, data)
        return root
```

BTree=BSTree()
root=BTree.addNode(20)
BTree.insert(root,25)
BTree.insert(root,15)
BTree.insert(root,10)
BTree.insert(root,5)
BTree.insert(root,13)
BTree.insert(root,23)
BTree.insert(root,23)

numLeft = countNodes(root->left);
numRight = countNodes(root->right);
numChildren = numLeft + numRight;